# Cell fracture doesn't work properly with solidify modifier

Tags: cell-fracture

I am pretty sure the issue is the solidify modifier I applied on the object before fracture it, but I don't understand why Cell Fracture breaks just some part of the mesh. It happens either with annotation pencil and own verts or child verts. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It’s a bit difficult to tell what’s going on since we don’t know how the mesh looks on the inside. Is it hollow?

Comment: please provide your blend file